# More efficient regex than ^(?:7+|9+8?|8)\s*$

Tags: regex, sas

Here is the regex I currently have:

```
^(?:7+|9+8?|8)\s*$
```

I need a regex pattern that matches the following strings:

```
'7'
'777777777777777'
'9'
'99999999999999999999'
'9999999999999998'
'8'
'7 '
'777777777777777 '
'9 '
'99999999999999999999 '
'9999999999999998  '
'8 '
```

That is to say, I need a regex that will match any of but only the following:

- A single 7, 8, or 9.
- A lot of 7s.
- A lot of 9s.
- A lot of 9s with a single 8 at the end.
- Any of the above with whitespace at the end.

I believe that my regex works for this.  Is there a better regex that does this?

I am using my regex in SAS, which I believe is very similar to Perl flavours.

Comment: To be honest, given the criteria it looks pretty much as good as you're going to get

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "efficient". Are you looking for a shorter regex? A faster one?

Comment: Something like`(7+|9*8?)\s` ought to work

Comment: what about "98"? :P match or not? if it needs to be matched, you didn't specify it, if it doesn't have to be matched, your current regex does match it... I mean "a lot of 9s" means more than one for me.

Comment: Why do you think it is _not_ efficient?

Comment: Your regex is as optimal as its going to get for what you're trying to do. Good job. Length *and* speed wise.

Comment: How much exactly is "*a lot*" for you? Is it more than 1?

Comment: @Gary: Nah, that would also match the empty string.

Comment: @Bergi, Yeah I noticed that ASA my edit time expired; being on my phone, I sat on correcting myself.  As random as that pattern seems, maybe blank strings are ok :-)  Just for the sake of redeeming my comment: `(?:\d)(7+|9*8?)\s?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine. You might think that it is not *optimal* because of multiple alternations that only look simple or clunky, but looking like that is all they do.

Simple is fine. Adding alternations, especially when you are using `^` and/or `$`, barely slows down your regex, as they are not checked if they're not needed to be. If you have regex `^(a*|b*)$` and your string is `aaaaa`, the `b*` alternation is not even checked. If your string is `cccc`, the first `c` is checked to be neither `a` or `b`, so it's effectivelly just a single character match extra for having the `b*` part.

What does slow down regexes is abundant use of quantifiers like `*` and `+`, something like `(b*?a*)*` (matching a single `b` takes 27 steps). Your regex has nothing like that, it is good and efficient.